# tflearn - <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'

Tags: python, ubuntu, tflearn

I am getting this error when trying to perform the basic operation of help in python for tflearn.

I wanted to know what is the reason for this and how to fix it.

Thanks!

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help('tflearn')
problem in tflearn - <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'
```

Comment: Try this: `sudo pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`; `sudo pip install --upgrade html5lib`; `sudo pip install spry` .

Comment: tired this, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using the `requests` package? In positive case, try: `sudo pip install --upgrade requests`.

Comment: magic! it worked!  thanks for the help....but can you help me understand why i was getting this error?

Comment: I read that it was a problem with a dependency of `requests` package in older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions found searching on the Internet:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade requests
```

This will upgrade the `requests` package, fixing the problem related to an older version of a dependency of this package.

Or upgrading the following packages solved the problem for other people:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
sudo pip install --upgrade html5lib
sudo pip install spry
```

I hope it helps.